# Разбить значения ключа масива по запятым

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив, значения которого

```
$allarea [0] = 202000
$allarea [0][1] = "Hudson,Bergen,Essex,Morris,Passaic"
$allarea [1] = 203000
$allarea [1][1] = "New Haven,Fairfield,Litchfield"
```

и так далее

Как с помощью explode разбить каждое значение ключа [*][1] по запятым?

Чтобы на выходе иметь что-то вроде:

```
$allarea [0] = 202000
$allarea [0][1] = "Hudson"
$allarea [0][2] = "Bergen"
$allarea [0][3] = "Essex"
$allarea [1] = 203000
$allarea [1][1] = "New Haven"
$allarea [1][2] = "Fairfield"
$allarea [1][3] = "Litchfield"
```

Comment: Получить массив с `explode` и присвоить в `$allarea[*]`,

Comment: а `$allarea [0] = 202000` это типа `$allarea [0][0] = 202000` ?  а то что-то сложно представить микс одновременно одномерного и двумерного массива в одной ячейке

Comment: Упс, извиняюсь. Конечно же, верно, это `$allarea [0][0] = 202000`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php. Ребята, ну это же первая ссылка по запросу `php explode`. Не стыдно?

Comment: Я честно прочитал документацию и немало времени поигрался с explode и foreach перед тем как  спрашивать здесь. Все равно сформировать нормальный код, чтобы получить на выходе нужный результат не выходило.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($allarea); ++$i) {
    if ($allarea[$i][1]) {
        $allarea[$i] = array_merge([$allarea[$i][0]], explode(',', $allarea[$i][1]));
    }
}
```

---

как тест использовал:

```
$arr = [[202000,
        'Hudson,Bergen,Essex,Morris,Passaic'],
        [203000,
        'New Haven,Fairfield,Litchfield']

];


echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';



for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); ++$i) {
    if ($arr[$i][1]) {
        $arr[$i] = array_merge([$arr[$i][0]], explode(',', $arr[$i][1]));
    }
}



echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

входной массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 202000
            [1] => Hudson,Bergen,Essex,Morris,Passaic
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 203000
            [1] => New Haven,Fairfield,Litchfield
        )    
)
```

выходной массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 202000
            [1] => Hudson
            [2] => Bergen
            [3] => Essex
            [4] => Morris
            [5] => Passaic
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 203000
            [1] => New Haven
            [2] => Fairfield
            [3] => Litchfield
        )    
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Подойдет?

```
for ($i=0; $i<Count($allarea); $i++) {
    if ($allarea[$i][1]) {
        $allarea[$i][1] = explode(",", $allarea[$i][1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понимаю как оно работает, оно же делает подмассив A[i][1][0]=1, A[i][1][1]=2, ... т.е. лишний уровень вложенности массива

Comment: А что вы проверяете if'ом ?

Comment: @Mike кстати прав, в результате получится не то, что требуется в вопросе.

Comment: @Zhenya40 посмотрите на array_spilice http://us3.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-splice.php C ним вы получите, что хотите

Comment: @splash58  if для того, что если вдруг нет элемента с перечислением, чтоб ошибку не выбило

Comment: @АлексейШиманский if вызовет такую же ошибку, это isset надо

Comment: @splash58 не вызовет `$arr =[];
$arr[0] = 23432;

if($arr[0][1]) {
echo 'yyyy';
} else {
echo 'noooo';
}`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский мда. это мне не нравится, даже вонинга не вызывает :( а как же вы отлаживаетесь? или пишите без ошибок ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Короткий способ:

```
$arr = [[202000,
         'Hudson,Bergen,Essex,Morris,Passaic'],
        [203000,
         'New Haven,Fairfield,Litchfield']];


$arr=array_map(function($a) {return explode(",","$a[0],$a[1]");},$arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить то, что хочется получить в вопросе, нужно делать как-то так:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < Count($allarea); $i++) {
   if ($allarea[$i][1]) {
      $allarea[$i] = array($allarea[$i][0], explode(',' $allarea[$i][1]));
   }
}
```

П.С. Я совсем не знаю PHP, если сработает `array($value, $other_array)`. Если нет, то:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < Count($allarea); $i++) {
   if ($allarea[$i][1]) {
      $temp = array($allarea[$i][0]));
      foreach(explode(',' $allarea[$i][1]) as $value) {
         array_push($temp, $value);
      }
      $allarea[$i] = $temp;
   }
}
```

Получится:

```
$allarea[0] == array(100500, "New York", "Georgetown", etc)
```